# Format excel with backcolor and uplaod to Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure

I am looking for solution to export to excel with cell background colour in .net and upload it to Azure blob. I am using openXMl to create excel file but changing stylesheet is quite tedious for openXMl therefore looking for some other solution

Comment: Hi, Have you test my solution? Any update?

Answer (score 0):

Below Code works fine on my side(Based on .Net Core):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
    ExcelPackage ExcelPkg = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet wsSheet1 = ExcelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    Color colFromHex = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B7DEE8");
    wsSheet1.Cells["A1:J3"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    wsSheet1.Cells["A1:J3"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colFromHex);
    using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet1.Cells[2, 2, 2, 2])
    {
        Rng.Value = "Welcome to Everyday be coding - tutorials for beginners";
        Rng.Style.Font.Size = 16;
        Rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        Rng.Style.Font.Italic = true;
    }
    wsSheet1.Protection.IsProtected = false;
    wsSheet1.Protection.AllowSelectLockedCells = false;
    Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
    ExcelPkg.SaveAs(ms);

    //Upload

    string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    string containerName = "test";
    string fileName = "Nex.xlsx";
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    ms.Position = 0;
    blobClient.Upload(ms);
}
```

Package references:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="5.5.0" />
```

Excel file(Azure portal don't support view the background color):

[image]

Comment: EPPlus is paid package. I was looking for some other solution . I used Interop.Excel and resolve my issues.